# Binary Weighted DAC

Tags: dac

I tried to do this question but do not understand what this graph is. I know it is a binary value for the D0,D1,D2,D3 inputs but what is the value ?

And is this the correct formula for final Vout?

$$ V_{out}= -(\frac{D3}{1}+\frac{D2}{2}+\frac{D1}{4}+\frac{D0}{8})*V_{in}*\frac{Rf}{R}$$

[image: QUESTION]

Comment: Slow down. If you only had one input, D3, what would the output voltage equation be?

Comment: Check your formula again. This isn't correct. _Remember_: This is a summing amplifier.

Comment: Hint: the x-axis in the graph is time. It's showing you different values for the inputs at different times.

Comment: Yes and the Y-axis shows the binary value 0v or 5v / 0 or 1..... but how does that give me a 4 digit number, im not seeing it haha

Comment: Do you know how a summing op-amp circuit works? If not then study that.

Comment: guys just please help me understand this graph

Comment: Think of the graphical representation as them being switches of when each resistor is connected to the amplifier. Look [here](http://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780195323030/student/pdf/DataConverters.pdf) at Figure 9.39 and Equations 9.109 to 9.111, this is from the Sedra/Smith textbook. Great textbook by the way... but I digress. Do you see how these resistor inputs are almost like switches? The switches just represent a duty cycle.

Comment: hm ok and does each switch just have a 1 or a 0 so whats the point of the graph ? like explain to me what the value for D0 is. is the value a 8bit number so it would be 01100110 (from the graph) ?

Comment: It isn't a 4-digit number.  It is a single 4-bit number with 16 possible values.  As you move through the chart from left to right, a vertical line drawn through all four bits will intersect them at different values as the line moves.  For example, if you examine the chart half way between the second and third dotted cursors, D0=1, D1=1, D2=0, D3=0.  So at that point in time, those are the inputs to the DAC circuit, and the circuit spits out a corresponding voltage.

Comment: ^^^ Exactly. This binary number will constantly change due to the duty cycle of each input. The equations I gave you in that link will give you a output voltage level representation of that binary number depending on the when a particular input is high or low.

Comment: graph is example input, if D0 is high at particular time,  then 1 = close switch = 5V.  Graph is shown to you because switchs are not constantly held in same position all the time,  i. e.  First all switches were open,  then D0 &  D2 were closed,  plug in D0 &  D1 = 1 and other Ds = 0,  Vref  =5 V and resistor values in correct equation   This will give you Vout for that particular time,  when switches are again operated,  Vout will change,  u r suppose to draw Vout for whole time period.

Comment: What is the output voltage from the opamp when D0 is 5 volts and all the other digital inputs are 0 volts? When you think you've worked that out ask yourself what the output will be when D1 is 5 volts and all the others are 0 volts. Then try the next step of D0 and D1 being 5 volts with the rest at 0 volts - what do you get - what are all the possible output voltages you can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a summing amplifier, the output voltage will change depending on when \$D_0,D_1,\$ etc. is on or off, which is provided to you in the graph on right.

First of all, let me explain how a voltage representation can determine a binary number. This graph below is not related to your problem but it is an **example** of how a binary number can change depending on the output. Everyone has seen the "stair step" DAC graph before.

[image]

Do you see how different output voltage can alter the binary number? This is an example of DAC. Now let's get back at your problem. You given the duty cycle of D1,D2, etc. Now look at this figure below.

[image]
This is from the Sedra/Smith (7th edition) textbook. Assuming that \$D_0,D_1,\$ etc. have the same input voltage, the binary number that will be represented when each input is high or low. The **output voltage** will tell you what binary number it's representing. Create truth table of each value to see the output voltage for every single possibility starting from 0000 to 1111. Now use your graph that was given to you and see at time \$t\$. Depending on that output voltage, you will see what binary value you will receive. Think of your graph that is given as **switches** for each network you have on the amplifier, like the picture above.

Comment: Thank you sir hopefully ill do well in my exam tomorrow :D

Comment: I hope i answered your question with good detail :)